# CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Master.Models.RawResponse' to 'Master.Application.Entities.RawResponse'

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

using (var context = new QuoteRequestContext())
                {

```
                context.RawResponse.Add(rawResponse); //Error on rawResponse
                context.PowerQuotes.Add(quote);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return responseBody;
    }
```

Comment: code only questions are discouraged

Comment: `Master.Models.RawResponse` and `Master.Application.Entites.RawResponse` are not the same class, that it why you can't add it.

Comment: can i know how to fix this ? i am not pretty sure.